Combine list of dataframes into one big dataframe avoiding duplicates on columns and indices
Multiple data points are in a list. I want to combine them into one pandas DataFrame. Minimal example:
list_of_frames = [pd.DataFrame({'name':'adam', 'height':'180'}, index=[0]), pd.DataFrame({'name':'adam', 'weight':'80'}, index=[1]), pd.DataFrame({'name':'eve', 'height':'190'}, index=[2])]

How do I obtain the following DataFrame?
    name    height  weight
0   adam    180     80
1   eve     190     NaN

If I call pd.concat(list_of_frames) I obtain a list of entries
    name    height  weight
0   adam    180     NaN
1   adam    NaN     80
2   eve     190     NaN

Obviously the height variable has been 'merged'. Can I collapse this DataFrame?
Alternatively I tried reduce(lambda l, r: pd.merge(l, r, on='name', how='outer'), list_of_frames) which leads to
    name    height_x    weight  height_y
0   adam    180     80  NaN
1   eve     NaN     NaN     190

Here we have separate column names. I feel like I am missing something obvious. Thanks for the help!

Can you have clashed in the data like: list_of_frames = [pd.DataFrame({'name':'adam', 'height':'180'}, index=[0]), pd.DataFrame({'name':'adam', 'height':'182'}, index=[1]), pd.DataFrame({'name':'eve', 'weight':'75'}, index=[2])]? What should be the output?

That cannot happen, each entry exists only once.

What can happen is that the metric repeats for another date.

Then you should also group by date .groupby(['name', 'date'], as_index=False), assuming 'date' is the appropriate column name

If you always have single rows DataFrames as input, "name" acts as unique key, use groupby.first:
pd.concat(list_of_frames).groupby('name', as_index=False).first()

Output:
   name height weight
0  adam    180     80
1   eve    190   None


There are some global values in a DataFrame with just one row and the name as a unique key. I will separate them and do as you said for those.
However, there are also DataFrames with multiple rows. They have a value for each name and date.

@Firefighting if there is no clash within those rows then this is not an issue. Give it a try and update your example if needed.

You are absolutely right. Thanks, much appreciated!

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list_of_frames = [
    pd.DataFrame({'name': 'adam', 'height': '180'}, index=[0]),
    pd.DataFrame({'name': 'adam', 'weight': '80'}, index=[1]),
    pd.DataFrame({'name': 'eve', 'height': '190'}, index=[2])
]

# Concatenate the list of frames into a single DataFrame
df = pd.concat(list_of_frames)
print(df)
# Group by 'name' and aggregate the columns
df_combined = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: next(iter(x.dropna()), np.nan))

df_combined = df_combined.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_combined)
'''
   name height weight
0  adam    180     80
1   eve    190    NaN
'''

